# Entity Framework - SaveChanges vs Transaction

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I have a bit stupid question, but I didn't find an answer.

Is there any difference between a single call to SaveChanges() and a single call to SaveChanges() inside a transaction? (I'm using Entity Framework in .net core 5 application)

I want to create a record in one table and update data in another one.

For example, it would be:

```
users.Password = "..."

var passwordReset = new PasswordReset(...)

_context.Add(passwordReset);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

And with transaction:

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    users.Password = "..."

    var passwordReset = new PasswordReset(...)

    _context.Add(passwordReset);
    _context.SaveChanges();

    transaction.Commit();
}
```

I want to ensure, that two queries will complete successfully but I don't know which option would be the best for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Genral DB rules: All operations of a transaction either fail or succeed to gether. If a transaction has multiple database changes they either all happen (on comit) or none happen (rollback). | Usually there are *implicit* transactions around very single Create, Update or Delete operation. This is save, but can have a impact on performance if you are doing bulk opeartions. | For bulk operations it is usually better to make one explicit transaction, so you do not waste a ton of time on the implicit "transaction start, operation, transaction comit" spam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is [there] any difference between single call [to] `SaveChanges()` and [a] single call [to] `SaveChanges()` inside a transaction? (I'm using Entity Framework in .net core 5 application)

Not really. A single call to `SaveChanges()` forms its own transaction. Using a transaction is a way to group multiple calls to `SaveChanges` together so they may all succeed or all fail (or have finer grained control to partly rollback on failure).

See the reference on [transactions in EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions)